# List of two-sided wallpaper groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetry

I'm interested in the symmetries of two-dimensional patterns that have two sides. In other words, what discrete groups can be formed from the three-dimensional Euclidean isometries which preserve a plane?

Is there a name for this type of group? Where can I find an enumeration of them?

Comment: Are you talking about discrete space symmetry groups that preserve a given plane? (So a reflection in the plane would count as separate from the identity, even though its action on the plane itself is trivial).

Comment: Right. I revised the question description to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are sometimes called “layer groups”, and there are 80 of them.  The layer groups, [Frieze groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group) and [rod groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_group) are together known in crystallography as “subperiodic groups”

There is a [Wikipedia article about layer groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_group) about them with several references, among them the *International Tables for Crystallography, Volume E: Subperiodic groups*.